# MPMovieplayerController playableDuration fluctuating for m3u8 files

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller, http-live-streaming

I am buffering a video which is in the m3u8 format and I am setting this url as the contenturl for MPMovieplayerController

I am running a background thread that runs every 0.3 seconds which I use to check the buffered and played duration and perform the check accordingly

```
if(!mPlaybackProgressTimer)
    mPlaybackProgressTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self selector:@selector(didPlayback:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES] retain];
```

and in didplayback

..

```
- (void)didPlayback:(id)sender {

    NSTimeInterval totalDuration = [mVideoPlayerController duration];

    NSTimeInterval playbackTime = [mVideoPlayerController currentPlaybackTime];
    float playbackProgress = 0.0;

   if(playbackTime > 0.0 && totalDuration > 0.0)
       playbackProgress = playbackTime / totalDuration;

   mPercentWatched = round(100 * playbackProgress);

   NSTimeInterval bufferedTime = [mVideoPlayerController playableDuration];
   float bufferProgress = 0.0;

   if(playbackTime > 0.0 && totalDuration > 0.0)
       bufferProgress = bufferedTime / totalDuration;

   [self setProgress:bufferProgress forProgressType:eProgressTypeBuffer];
   [self setProgress:playbackProgress forProgressType:eProgressTypePlay];
}
```

The problem is that the *bufferedTime* is fluctuating under certain circumstances :-
 - I the m3u8 files divided into separate files for different resolutions and bitrates
 - I have an index.m3u8 file which dicides which m3u8 file to serve for what bandwidth
 - Of course it does not serve up the whole m3u8 file but individual *.ts files based on how the user will have the best experience without any delay (all this is managed internally)
 - Also i have followed all this in accordance with the [apple developer guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html)

I'm not sure why the fluctuation is happening but what seems to make sense to me is that .. certain amount of data is buffered but then i think that data may be being discarded (just a theory)

**Note:** I am using encoding.com to segment the media

UPDATE: Logs

2013-01-14 11:46:57.731 IronStudios[7724:c07] Buffer Progress : 0.139779
2013-01-14 11:46:57.930 IronStudios[7724:c07] Buffer Progress : 0.139779
2013-01-14 11:46:58.130 IronStudios[7724:c07] Buffer Progress : 0.139790
2013-01-14 11:46:58.331 IronStudios[7724:c07] Buffer Progress : 0.139790
2013-01-14 11:46:58.530 IronStudios[7724:c07] Buffer Progress : 0.125042
2013-01-14 11:46:58.730 IronStudios[7724:c07] Buffer Progress : 0.126391
2013-01-14 11:46:58.930 IronStudios[7724:c07] Buffer Progress : 0.124450
2013-01-14 11:46:59.130 IronStudios[7724:c07] Buffer Progress : 0.125799

as you can see the buffer progress is reducing on certain instances.

Comment: Why do you expect the playableDuration to remain fixed?  The player is reading ahead and playing concurrently.

Comment: Can you add some NSLogs to show what bufferedTime is over time, and include it in your question?

Comment: @danh im sorry i was not clear ..
by fluctuating what i really mean is that the duration is reducing ..

Answer (score 0):

The duration could be derived from the amount downloaded, whereas the playableDuration is derived from what can be played back.

iOS will only start playback of a mpeg2-ts chunk once the entire chunk has been downloaded.

Suppose you're using 10 second chunks.

```
Downloaded: 2.2 chunks (22 seconds)
Playable:   2   chunks (20 seconds)
Progress bar = 2 / 2.2 = ~91%
```

A couple of seconds later....

```
Downloaded: 2.9 chunks (29 seconds)
Playable:   2   chunks (20 seconds)
Progress bar = 2 / 2.9 = ~69%
```

Your progress bar has gone backwards...

A couple of seconds later....

```
Downloaded: 3.1 chunks (31 seconds)
Playable:   3   chunks (30 seconds)
Progress bar = 3 / 3.1 = ~97%
```

and forwards again...

Comment: well i am considering the playableDuration when trying to calculate the buffer time and as you can see that increments only once an entire chunk is downloaded .. am i right .. ?